# How to migrate the database when renaming an ActiveRecord model that is a subclass of a base class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I write a Rails migration to rename an ActiveRecord subclass when the models are stored in the database using single table inheritance (STI)? The only thing I can think of is to use a raw sql update statement to change the value of type column value from the old subtype name to the new one.

Comment: Are you trying to rename the string text stored in `type` column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`execute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute) to run raw queries in the migrations

```
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "UPDATE table_name SET type = 'Namespace::NewSubclass' WHERE type = 'Namespace::OldSubclass'"
  end

  def down
    execute "UPDATE table_name SET type = 'Namespace::OldSubclass' WHERE type = 'Namespace::NewSubclass'"
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like up and down queries should be swapped here.

Comment: `up` moves forward in the sequence of migrations. `down` moves backwards.

Comment: I mean that `up` method should run `execute "UPDATE table_name SET type = 'Namespace::NewSubclass' WHERE type = 'Namespace::OldSubclass'"`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer. Sorry for being dense!

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4 lets you define a [`reversible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-i-reversible) migration for @deefour's answer:

```
def change
  rename_sti_type :table_name, 'Namespace::OldSubclass', 'Namespace::NewSubclass'
end

def rename_sti_type(table_name, old_type, new_type)
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { execute "UPDATE #{table_name} SET type = '#{new_type}' WHERE type = '#{old_type}'" }
    dir.down { execute "UPDATE #{table_name} SET type = '#{old_type}' WHERE type = '#{new_type}'"}
  end
end
```

You could generalise this into a `change_data(table, field, old_value, new_value)` method; but be mindful that if the up migration sets the type/field to a `new_value` which is already in use, then the down migration will also change existing rows which already had `new_value` value into `old_value`.